# Make UIWebView not to break words like th}is

Tags: html, uiwebview, mobile-safari, line-breaks, ios

I have a UIWebView, its contents is loaded from a local HTML file. It contains words like this: `abc}defg`. UIWebView may "auto-hyphenate" it into 2 lines:

```
blah blah blah abc}
defg.
```

Is there a way to customize it to break lines only with spaces?

In-built Safari browser (iOS 5.1.1) has the same behavior. It also splits `abc}defg` into 2 lines if necessary.

Something like `<nobr>` tag for these words. (The tag itself needs a lot of replaces to be done, which greatly reduces the performance.)

Comment: For what it's worth I can't replicate your issue on 6.0.

Comment: For what? Symbols `} |` etc. mean letters in Church Slavonic fonts.